# Conditionally using WP8.1 features

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In a project that's targeting Windows Phone 8.0, is there a way to conditionally use WP8.1 features while retaining compatibility with 8.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not.  If you need wp 8.1 features you need to target wp 8.1.  According to adduplex 77.8% of windows phones are using wp 8.1 with 8.9 using wp8.

The only option to do this is to create a project that has a portable class library, wp8 and wp8.1 project in it.  Put as much of code in the portable class library as possible.  Publish both versions of the app.  I would use something like MVVMLight for this